# how to add custom skin for textField in javafx using css?

Tags: javafx

I am trying to add a default skin to text Field using css but its not working as i expect it to.
I expect a right button in text Field like one's in Metro theme of Win8.
Here is fxml i am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" stylesheets="@custom.css"         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <children>
      <TextField layoutX="126.0" layoutY="138.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is css :

```
.text-field{
    -fx-skin: "application.MetroTextFieldSkin";
}
```

And here are 2 skin classes i am using :

first one :

```
package application;

import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

/**
 * Created by pedro_000 on 12/5/13.
 */
public class MetroTextFieldSkin extends TextFieldWithButtonSkin{
    public MetroTextFieldSkin(TextField textField) {
        super(textField);
    }

    protected void rightButtonPressed()
    {
        getSkinnable().setText("");
    }

}
```

2nd one :

```
package application;

import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;


public class TextFieldWithButtonSkin extends TextFieldSkin{
    private StackPane rightButton;
    private Region rightButtonGraphic;

    protected TextField textField;

    public TextFieldWithButtonSkin(TextField textField) {
        super(textField);

        this.textField = textField;

        rightButton = new StackPane();
        rightButton.getStyleClass().setAll("right-button");
        rightButton.setFocusTraversable(false);

        rightButtonGraphic = new Region();
        rightButtonGraphic.getStyleClass().setAll("right-button-graphic");
        rightButtonGraphic.setFocusTraversable(false);

        rightButtonGraphic.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        rightButtonGraphic.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        rightButton.setVisible(false);
        rightButtonGraphic.setVisible(false);

        rightButton.getChildren().add(rightButtonGraphic);
        getChildren().add(rightButton);

        setupListeners();
    }

    private void setupListeners() {

        final TextField textField = getSkinnable();
        rightButton.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                rightButtonPressed();
            }
        });
        rightButton.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                rightButtonReleased();
            }
        });

        textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                textChanged();
            }
        });
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                focusChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void textChanged()
    {
        if (textField.getText() == null)
            return;
        System.out.println(textField.getText().isEmpty());
        rightButton.setVisible(!textField.getText().isEmpty());
        rightButtonGraphic.setVisible(!textField.getText().isEmpty());
    }

    protected void focusChanged()
    {
        if (textField.getText() == null)
            return;

        rightButton.setVisible(textField.isFocused() && !textField.getText().isEmpty());
        rightButtonGraphic.setVisible(textField.isFocused() && !textField.getText().isEmpty());
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, h);

        final double clearGraphicWidth = snapSize(rightButtonGraphic.prefWidth(-1));
        final double clearButtonWidth = rightButton.snappedLeftInset() + clearGraphicWidth + rightButton.snappedRightInset();

        rightButton.resize(clearButtonWidth, h);
        positionInArea(rightButton,
                (x+w) - clearButtonWidth, y,
                clearButtonWidth, h, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    protected void rightButtonPressed()
    {
    }

    protected void rightButtonReleased()
    {

    }

}
```

Am i missing something which is necessary to make it work.
These are actualy created by pedro for his theme jMetro.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231654/createdefaultskin-returned-null-error-in-javafx-custom-control

Comment: No it does not........!

Comment: Background blog post on [creating custom JavaFX UI controls with the skin class referenced by `-fx-skin` in CSS](http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-1/).

Comment: Thanks it was good but that's not what i'm looking for.